# binascii.Error: Incorrect padding in django ?- when redirected to django adminsitration page

Tags: python, django

I was doing a project in Django. I added a crispy template pack and some bootstrap to the project after sometime when I tried to redirect to the Django administration page suddenly it's showing a padding error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1QWx.jpg)

if someone happens to have this error please tell how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same error. when I tried to put 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of localhost:8000 it worked fine or which browser are you using? try another browser instead of your current browser.